# fail upload to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to save a image file name at database, but i cannot make it, please help me
my database have no wrong, duno why it cannot update to databse, but i can get the $newname  correctly

```
?php session_start(); 
include_once("connectDB.php"); 
$ID = $_SESSION['ID'];

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
$ID = $_SESSION['ID'];
$loc = "profilepicture/";

if($_FILES["Adminpic"]["type"] == "image/png" || $_FILES["Adminpic"]["type"] ==     
"image/jpeg" || $_FILES["Adminpic"]["type"] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES["Adminpic"]
["type"] == "image/gif")
{
$ID = $_SESSION['ID'];
$file = explode(".", $_FILES["Adminpic"]["name"]);
$newname = "$ID.$file[0].$file[1]";
mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET Adminpic == '$newname' WHERE ID='$ID'");


$path = "$loc$newname";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Adminpic"]["tmp_name"], $path)  ;
echo "Your image has been uploaded success, $newname";

} 
else{
echo"invalid file.";
} 
}
```

Comment: exact error message is?

Comment: put your error checking on place

Comment: that is no error , but cannot update to database

Comment: run teamviewer and ill help u

Comment: you have no error checking, so of course you don't see an error

Comment: because i m still new in php, Gunr jesra can u help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Because your query is incorrect

```
  mysql_query("UPDATE admin SET Adminpic ='$newname' WHERE ID=$ID");
```

try with this because you use double equal after Adminpic .

Comment: @karheng5321: just to make sure, did you also remove the single quotes from `$ID`?

Comment: can some 1 add me google+ or gmail me ? need help urgent
karheng5321@gmail.com

Comment: try to print the variable $ID and make sure if he have a value in it and make sure if all your variable have values 

and make sure to use the query that i gives to you .

Comment: i can update other detail by in <input type="text">, but only file type cannot update to database

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: allowed_array in C:\xampp\htdocs\FYP\admineditprofile.php on line 9

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\FYP\admineditprofile.php on line 9